# given a list of urls how can i return the content of that urls from a generator asyncronously using twisted python

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, twisted

I want to know how to return the content of a list of urls asynchronously using twisted in python. I know i can use getPage() to get the url content asynchronously but how can i use the result with yield of the generator to return the result from the generator function.

synchronous code looks like this

```
import requests
def gen(urls):
    for url in urls:
        yield requests.get(url)
```

**Edit 1:**

my specific requirement is to provide a service through flask python. which is, given a keyword my flask application should return the content of all urls related to that keyword. i can get list of urls from a keyword using a search engine api, all i have to do is return the content using server sent events (event source) as streaming service.

```
def handle_request():
    urls=search_engine.search(requests.args.get('query'))
    def content_gen():
        for url in urls:
            yield requests.get(url)
    return Response(content_gen(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

the requests.get call is synchronous, all i want is to make the code asynchronous by using getPage() of twisted for my flask application

**EDIT 2:**

by using Twisted's getPage on all urls i am going to get a list of deferreds. Flask is a synchronous framework, so i cant directly use deferreds to return data through Flask. By using crochet library i can wait on deferreds synchronously since waiting on deferred is blocking using @wait.for decorator in crochet, the results are returned sequentially. But i want the generator function to yield the data of url whichever is available rather than following the url sequence.

Honestly I don't know much about crochet or twisted, so if i am asking a trivial question please excuse me.

Comment: And what part of the transformation are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I want a generator function which yields the content of the url whenever the content for any url is available @Jean-PaulCalderone

Comment: Flask will still want the results to arrive synchronously.  You can integrate asynchronous Twisted code with other synchronous code in a variety of ways - one way is with Itamar Turner-Trauring's Crochet library.  If the problem you're having is async/sync integration, that's worth a look.  I'm still not sure which part of the solution you're stuck on, though.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone , Can you please checkout Edit 2.